# How do i call two of three existent functions randomly

Tags: python, random

I use of 3 functions with arguments in Python: `Func1(a,b), Func2(c,d), Func3(e,f)` . all i want is how to call two different functions of these three functions randomly. i have the below code for calling  a function randomly too. how could i convert this code to that one which call 2 functions (which is not the same) randomly.

```
Mylist = [functools.partial(Func1, a, b), functools.partial(Func2, c, d), functools.partial(Func3, e, f)]
random.choice(Mylist)()
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
for func in random.sample(Mylist, 2):
    func()
```

Comment: Done it. Thank you very much for your effective help my friend.